# When tags are merged, are followers merged too?

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, followers

When two tags are merged, are followers of the old tag moved onto the new tag? If not, should this happen?

Or am I not understanding something about how the merging process works?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, tag watchers get moved to the new tag.**

I just tried this here on Meta.SE with two tags that are going to be gotten rid of - [forum](/questions/tagged/forum) and [forums](/questions/tagged/forums). I added [forum](/questions/tagged/forum) to my watched tags, and @Tinkeringbell [merged [forum] into [forums]](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7446096).

[forums](/questions/tagged/forums) then appeared in my watched tags list.